# MongoDB Sort Operation returning single value for the field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I was trying to sort the _id field desc and return only one max value for it but having issue around it

below one is returning all the fields

db.people.find().sort({_id:-1}).limit(1)

below one is retuning multiple values for the field

db.people.aggregate({$project: { _id:1}},{ $sort:{_id:-1}})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below query

```
db.MyColl.find({},{_id:1}).sort({_id:-1}).limit(1)
```